# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when trying to read my datagridview when inserted own values

Tags: c#, datagridview, null

```
string[,] Datavalue = new string[GridDelivery.Rows.Count - 1, GridDelivery.Columns.Count];

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridDelivery.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn Col in GridDelivery.Columns)
    {
       // error occurs on this line of code
       Datavalue[row.Index, Col.Index] = GridDelivery.Rows[row.Index].Cells[Col.Index].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am really struggling with this for the past few days and really can't seem to figure out why it is giving me null. I use the datagridview as my input to get value might that be the reason, if it is please help me find something similar so It can have an easy input.

Included -1 to the GridDelivery.Rows otherwise it read the last row and gave null, but otherwise have no clue how to resolve this issue. GUI is linked  ==>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So6qH.png)

and error displayed after being in debug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3OGH.jpg)

Comment: In which line does this error occur?

Comment: Datavalue[row.Index, Col.Index] = GridDelivery.Rows[row.Index].Cells[Col.Index].Value.ToString();

Comment: on which colomn and row does it throw an exception? even at first? or only second, where you really don't have data? I'm years from data grid views, but maybe the "index" isn't zero based, and you put it into a zero based array?

Comment: Just added everything displayed so as far as I know, basically to answer your question...I don't really know either. :*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your code to :

```
string[,] Datavalue = new string[GridDelivery.Rows.Count, GridDelivery.Columns.Count];

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridDelivery.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn Col in GridDelivery.Columns)
    {
       Datavalue[row.Index, Col.Index] = GridDelivery.Rows[row.Index].Cells[Col.Index]?.Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

I recommend reading these articles:

[Jagged Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

[null conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Thanks, It seemed to have worked, could you maybe explain to me what the question marks do next to the value and cells ?

Comment: I added the link to the article `null conditional operators`, but if you don't understand, let me know so I can explain it better